dnf-automatic: reboot not happen
I have the following settings of dnf-automatic conf.
apply_updates = yes
reboot = when-needed

Update does happen, but reboot not. The new kernel is installed and set as default. In such case, reboot is not needed? I am no system admin expert, just wondering if it is right. Shouldn't it reboot when kernel changed?
kernel.x86_64                                 4.18.0-553.5.1.el8_10                      @rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms
kernel.x86_64                                 4.18.0-553.22.1.el8_10                     @rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms
kernel-core.x86_64                            4.18.0-553.5.1.el8_10                      @rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms
kernel-core.x86_64                            4.18.0-553.22.1.el8_10                     @rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms
kernel-modules.x86_64                         4.18.0-553.5.1.el8_10                      @rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms
kernel-modules.x86_64                         4.18.0-553.22.1.el8_10                     @rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms
kernel-tools.x86_64                           4.18.0-553.22.1.el8_10                     @rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms
kernel-tools-libs.x86_64                      4.18.0-553.22.1.el8_10                     @rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms


probably related to that: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/1eknfj7/dnf_automatic_used_on_test_boxes_not_rebooting/
